# Make percentage completion

Tags: c, shell, makefile

I am wondering if at all it is possible to generate a completion percentage for a given Makefile execution? I have a Makefile which runs sum tests, the output is hidden from the user for UI purposes, however, I am wondering if I can perhaps give a percentage indication of the execution of that Makefile.

NO code as, I have no idea how to even pursue this and am just looking for pointers.

Also, even if you did get a percentage figure from make, how could we update it in the shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's no way for make itself to give this information, because make doesn't know.  Make does NOT work by first computing all the targets that will need to be rebuilt, then building them.  Rather, make works by walking the dependency graph one node at a time, until finally there's no work left to do.  Since make doesn't know how many targets will be built until it's done, it can't provide a percentage complete value.

The only way for you to do this would be if YOU compute the a percentage value, by virtue of knowing how many targets there are and which target is currently running.  You'd have to write this information into your recipes.

Comment: I agree. The way to do it would be have a shell script at the start of every target, and do two runs - the first run use the shell script to increment something, or ie `echo "+" >> count.txt`.  Then count the +'s and create a second file "total.txt" with that number.  On the second and subsequent runs of the shell script, detect if total.txt is present at the top level, and compare the amount completed so far to the total.txt.  Then your script can output that to stderr, so a `make all >> /dev/null` would still report the % completed.